# How to install Visual Paradigm on Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins, visual-paradigm

I'm following the instructions [here](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2381/2384/66569_overviewandi.html) but it seems not to work. I'll contact the developer, but wonder if someone has been able to make it work somehow.

The installation process is completed, but Netbeans doesn't see the plug-in. I assume it is deployed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it got fixed but suddenly upon starting the IDE an update for the plugin showed up and it started working afterwards.